# Is there a way to avoid clean-build and clean server in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a web-project with `eclipse kepler` and I have to continiously to do the clean-build and clean-server operation to run my changes on a server correctly. I find it very unconvenient, is there a way to avoid to do that? I just don't know how eclipse works. I suspect it aches some files, therefore I have to delete this files via clea-build to run actual project version.

Comment: have you checked the option *build automatically*?

Comment: @SpringLearner No, it doesn't what I want. Because it's gonna rebuild the entire project after I've made changes. I want to publish actual changes without that _clean operations_.

Comment: If you are working with `tomcat` install the `WTP` [Web Tools Platform] plugin which allows you to make the deployment on the fly as and when you save your changes.

Comment: @G.S Yeah, I'm working exactly with tomcat. Does that plugin suit the only for tomcat?

Comment: I think yes. Hope there are some other plugins available for different servers